# Which Aggregate function in mongoDB should I use?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, delete-record

I have a collection as follows:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6100b7c226aa5c7c0bb665e1"
    },
    "empId": "101962700",
    "Result": "NotEnrolled",
    "enrollDate": "4/21/2021",
    "Name": "THOMAS Edison",
    "Flag": "NEGATIVE",
    "createdDateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-06-30T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
} 
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6100b7c226aa5c7c0bb665e1"
    },
    "empId": "101962700",
    "Result": "NotEnrolled",
    "enrollDate": "5/21/2021",
    "Name": "THOMAS Edison",
    "Flag": "NEGATIVE",
    "createdDateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-06-30T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6100b7c226aa5c7c0bb665e1"
    },
    "empId": "101962700",
    "Result": "NotEnrolled",
    "enrollDate": "5/21/2021",
    "Name": "THOMAS Edison",
    "Flag": "NEGATIVE",
    "createdDateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-06-30T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6100b7c226aa5c7c0bb665e1"
    },
    "empId": "101962701",
    "Result": "Enrolled",
    "enrollDate": "4/21/2021",
    "Name": "Jim Miller",
    "Flag": "NEGATIVE",
    "createdDateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-06-30T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
} 
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6100b7c226aa5c7c0bb665e1"
    },
    "empId": "101962701",
    "Result": "Enrolled",
    "enrollDate": "5/21/2021",
    "Name": "Jim Miller",
    "Flag": "NEGATIVE",
    "createdDateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-06-30T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6100b7c226aa5c7c0bb665e1"
    },
    "empId": "101962701",
    "Result": "Enrolled",
    "enrollDate": "5/21/2021",
    "Name": "Jim Miller",
    "Flag": "NEGATIVE",
    "createdDateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-06-30T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

Now by mistake 20 records for same `empID` with the same date ('5/21/2021') got inserted in the DB. I want to keep only 1 record for that date and employee in the DB and delete rest 19 records.
that means for `empID` I only want to keep record with `"enrollDate":"4/21/2021"` and 1 record with `"enrollDate":"5/21/2021"` and delete duplicate records for the `"enrollDate":"5/21/2021"`. Same for
`"empId":"101962701"`.

How can I form delete query in Mongodb?

Expected Output

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6100b7c226aa5c7c0bb665e1"
    },
    "empId": "101962700",
    "Result": "NotEnrolled",
    "enrollDate": "4/21/2021",
    "Name": "THOMAS Edison",
    "Flag": "NEGATIVE",
    "createdDateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-06-30T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
} 
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6100b7c226aa5c7c0bb665e1"
    },
    "empId": "101962700",
    "Result": "NotEnrolled",
    "enrollDate": "5/21/2021",
    "Name": "THOMAS Edison",
    "Flag": "NEGATIVE",
    "createdDateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-06-30T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6100b7c226aa5c7c0bb665e1"
    },
    "empId": "101962701",
    "Result": "Enrolled",
    "enrollDate": "4/21/2021",
    "Name": "Jim Miller",
    "Flag": "NEGATIVE",
    "createdDateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-06-30T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
} 

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6100b7c226aa5c7c0bb665e1"
    },
    "empId": "101962701",
    "Result": "Enrolled",
    "enrollDate": "5/21/2021",
    "Name": "Jim Miller",
    "Flag": "NEGATIVE",
    "createdDateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-06-30T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

I want to remove duplicate `empId` with `enrollDate`.

Comment: try to format your data better, try something like [this](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print), also put your data in code blocks

Answer (score 1):

Would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { empId: "$empId", enrollDate: "$enrollDate" },
      data: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Gb5RHXNRui)